# CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms display blank page when running on C# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, chromium, cefsharp

I really don't know what is wrong but since so many hours I just want to run the [sample application](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) but after downloading the .zip file and launch the project from the file CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms it seem to be built well after a while the the form display...loading the google page.... then the Windows keep showing the BLANK PAGE (See the image attached to my post) forever...As I did not change anything in the code of the sample application then I don't understand what is wrong at all. My working environment is:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
  version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Microsoft .NET Framework
  version 4.6.01055
- Microsoft Visual C# 2015
- Windows 10 OS
  Notice also that I'm a beginner to C# and I use Nuget to manager the package.
  Thank in advanced

[image]

Comment: If your using the x64 build try x86. There is a known issue that's listed in the release notes

Comment: Thank you ! it works fine with x86  !  also do you know how I can display the forms with all the controls in visual studio in order to edit it with graphically ? for now I just see the generated code in BrowserForm.Designer.cs

Comment: There is no designer support